# php will not allow me to do `shell_exec('git pull origin master 2>&1');`

Tags: centos, php, git

When I run the script `<?php chdir('/var/www/html'); echo shell_exec('git pull origin master 2>&1'); ?>`, I get the error message:

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

Here's what I did:

```
ssh apache@example.com
pwd # shows that I'm already at /var/www as my home directory
ls .ssh/ # shows that I have id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, and id_rsa.pub is given to github
cd html
git pull origin master # everything downloads perfectly
echo "<?php chdir('/var/www/html'); echo shell_exec('git pull origin master 2>&1'); " > pull.php
```

Now when I go to `http://example.com/pull.php` I get the error `cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied` .

To confirm my permissions, I logged in as root to do a `chown -R apache:apache /var/www`.  I also have this in my `/etc/passwd`

```
apache:x:48:48:Apache:/var/www:/bin/bash
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please check whether your version of PHP is built using ZTS (`php -i`). This looks like the `chdir` could be ignored by the forked shell, see the 'Caution' at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php.  Also worth checking SELinux contexts if running CentOS/RHEL.

Comment: SUCCESS!! Thanks! I had to disable SELINUX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux does not allow the web server to write to random directories. You need to explicitly define what directories SELinux should allow to be writable by setting their default context to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` and then setting the context of any existing files. For example:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www(/.*)?"
restorecon -rv /var/www
```

You almost certainly should not make the entire site writable by the web server though, nor set up a web page which directly calls `git`. Both of these completely negate any security benefits you would have gotten from SELinux, and the latter has its own set of potential problems.